# Show list players name from for into select option view form

Tags: angularjs

As I can show the list of only the names of the players in the view within a select options as seen in the attached photo. In a html5 form how to display the list of names?

// players.js

```
 var db = firebase.database().ref('players/');
  db.on('value', function(snapshot){
    var players = snapshot.val();
    var player = '';
    for (player in players) {

         console.log(players[player].name); //show list name of players

    }
  }, function(errorObject) {
    console.log("error");
  })
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N1CB.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your expected is, do you want a dropdown with player names?

Comment: That's right, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ehy37aa2/13/).

```
<select ng-options="p as p.name for p in players" ng-model="selected">
```

The `ng-options="p as p.name for p in players"` populates your dropdown list, and `ng-model="selected"` defines a model named `selected` which holds the selected `player` object.

Comment: Works but the names are already predefined. But in my example there is a for ...

Or how do I save the for iteration within $ scope?

Comment: Have the server return a `JSON` array. Then you can just assign it to `players`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks A2H, my code works:

```
    $scope.players = [];
     var db = firebase.database().ref('players/');
     db.on('value', function(snapshot){
     var players = snapshot.val();
     var player = '';
     for (player in players) {

     $scope.players.push({name:players[player].name})
   }
  }, function(errorObject) {
    console.log("error");
  })
```

html5:

```
    <label>Slected player: {{selected}}</label><br>
    <select ng-options="p as p.name for p in players" ng-model="selected">

    </select>
```

Comment: If `snapshot.val()` returns a `JSON` array, then you don't need to iterate and push elements into the `$scope.players` array. Try this: `$scope.players = snapshot.val()` and get rid of the rest of the code.